# How can I copy a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, test-environments

I have a CRM 4.0 solution in production and I would like to make a replica of it so that I can use it as a test server.

What are the alternatives to accomplish this? Cons / Pros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up following the process from Microsoft:

"How to move the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 deployment"

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/952934

It looked like there was not another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can export all of your customizations to a file and then import them into your test system.  Ideally you will work the other direction (make changes in test, then move to production).

To Export, go to Settings-Customization.  You will see options for Import Customizations and Export Customizations.  If you click Export Customizations, you can export selected entity customizations.  Also there is a menu option to export all customizations.  CRM will create a .zip file which is an XML file that includes the entity definitions, forms, views, relationships, and workflows.  You just reverse the process to import your changes into another environment.

Comment: Visiting the post, after quite some time :) This is one option, but it does not create a replica. At least the data will be missing.